# Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'. in panda doc in safari browser

Tags: c#, jquery, iframe

I am using `panda doc` for e-signature in documents but when I open the document in `panda doc` editor, it gives the following error:

> [Error] Refused to display 'https://app.pandadoc.com/login/?next=/a/#/document/v1/editor/document-id' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

This error occurred in Safari browser only. Can anyone fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly In safari there is a known issue of authorization. You need to authorize it first, then it will work. You need to turn on **Enable cross-site tracking**. Then it will work fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You Need to turn on uncheck **Prevent cross-site tracking** on safari browser

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).